# Google App Engine (Python 2.7) Helloworld will not open in browser via GAE Launcher

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to run the Google App Engine Python 2.7 Hello World program and view it in the browser via Google App Engine Launcher. I followed the install and program instructions to the letter. I copied and pasted the code in the instructions to the helloworld.py file and app.yam1 and verified that they are the same. I hit run on the launcher and it runs with no errors, although I get no sign that is has completed. I get the following from the logs:

*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080 --admin_port=8000
Python command: /opt/local/bin/python2.7

When I try to open in the browser via the GAE Launcher, the 'browse' icon is grayed out and the browser won't open. I tried opening localhost:8080
in Firefox and Chrome as the tutorial suggests, but I get unable to connect errors from both.

How can I view Hello World in a browser?

Comment: Which version of GAE SDK do you use? Please open the console log from main window of the Launcher and copy/paste here.

Comment: GAE 1.7.7. From the logs:


*** Running dev_appserver with the following flags:
    --skip_sdk_update_check=yes --port=8080 --admin_port=8000
Python command: /opt/local/bin/python2.7